# Finding the $2001th$ term of the given series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1-a_n}$ for $n \geq1$ and $a_1=a_3$. Find $(a_{2001})^{2001}$.

Options are 
$(A)$ $1$

$(B)$ $-1$

$(C)$ $0$

$(D)$ None of these

Putting $n=1,2$ and using $a_1=a_3$, I got $a_1^{2}-a_1+1=0$ which has imaginary roots. How to proceed from here? Or is there any better method?

Comment: You have $a$ to the $2001$, to the $2001$. Is there any chance that one of the $2001$ is a subscript?

Comment: @RGS Thanks for pointing it out. Correction has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{1-a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-a_{n}}}=\frac{1-a_n}{1-a_n-1}=\frac{a_n-1}{a_n}=1-\frac1{a_n}$$
$$\implies a_{n+4}=1-\frac1{a_{n+2}}=1-\frac1{1-\frac1{a_n}}=\frac{a_n-1-a_n}{a_n-1}=\frac1{1-a_n}=a_{n+1}$$
This gives us that $$a_n=a_{n+3},\,\,\forall n\ge1$$
Thus
$$2001\equiv0\mod 3\implies a_{2001}=a_3=a_1$$
Solving the equation you have gives $$a_1=\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}\,\,(=(-1)^{\frac13}),\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\,\,(=-(-1)^{\frac23})\\ \implies (a_{2001})^{2001}={a_1}^{2001}=\begin{cases}(-1)^{667}\\-(-1)^{1334}\end{cases}=-1$$

Comment: Of course, expressions $$(-1)^{\frac13}\qquad(-1)^{\frac23}$$ should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: @Did Yes, good point, I simply used them here since they end up being cubed anyway.

Comment: Not a good idea, either from a mathematical or from a pedagogical point of view, sorry.